# Python referenced before assignment error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a hangman game with pygame. The game itself is irrelevant for this. I defined a variable early on in my code, then later, when a function is called that uses the variable, Python returns a "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'guessedLetters' referenced before assignment" Both the function and the call are later in my code than the variable assignment. This is the variable assignment:
`guessedLetters = ""`.

This is the function:

```
def guess(letter):
    if letter in word:
        pass
    else:
        guessedLetters += '  ' + letter
        hangmanStage += 1
```

This is where it is called(which is within another method):

```
def redrawWindow():
    win.fill((150, 150, 150))
    drawLetters()
    drawGuessedLetters()
    drawHangman()
```

And this is where that method is called

```
while running:
    for event in ...
    redrawWindow()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

`guessedLetters` should be declared inside the function if use is local or outside if it is global.

In first case, if it is declared outside function, add a `global guessedLetters` before referencing to it.

If it is local then add `guessedLetters = ''` on top.

Do this for other variables like `hangmanStage` too.

Comment: Don't you think it might be better to pass in `guessedLetters` and then, after modifying it, return it to the caller?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 thats better instead with a `return` statement